# Code is in Infinite Loop and I don't know Why

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code is stuck in an infinite loop on the following lines:

```
   while i <= len(mylist):
        if mylist[i][j] == number:
```

I've stepped through the code but still do not know how to fix it. The problem I'm trying to solve is as follows:

Define a procedure, check_sudoku,
 that takes as input a square list
 of lists representing an n x n
 sudoku puzzle solution and returns the boolean
 True if the input is a valid
 sudoku square and returns the boolean False
 otherwise.

A valid sudoku square satisfies these
 two properties:

1. Each column of the square contains
      each of the whole numbers from 1 to n exactly once.
2. Each row of the square contains each
      of the whole numbers from 1 to n exactly once.

   You may assume that the input is square and contains at
   least one row and column.

The below code I've written should check for just the row, not the column. Any advice on how to fix it and what I've done wrong would be greatly appreciate, so I'll understand and not make the mistake again.

```
def check_sudoku(mylist):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    number = len(mylist)
    while i <= len(mylist):
        if mylist[i][j] == number:
            number = number - 1
            j = 0
            if number == 0:
                i = i + 1
                number = len(mylist)
            else:
                j = j + 1
                if number not in list:
                    break
                    return False
    return True



check_sudoku([[1, 2, 3, 4],
              [1, 3, 1, 4],
              [3, 1, 2, 3],
              [4, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: You increment `i` if `number == 0`, but not otherwise. That's where your problem lies

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia I'm using PyCharm.

Comment: Look at what happens if `mylist[i][j]` != `number`, as is the case here.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thank you for your reply. My code isn't hitting where 'if number == 0'. Does that make a difference? It's failing way before that.

Comment: @EFT That is it! I knew it was something easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to explain the function with the list you supplied as an example.

What's happening is:

```
number = len(mylist)
```

number = 4

```
while 0 <= 4
    if 1 == 4: // This condition will never be true and therefore doesn't run the code below it
```

The while will run again and the same will happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this line

```
        print("i: " + str(i) + " j: " + str(j))
```

Just under where the While Loop starts, you realise that i and j never increment and it stays on the first spot.

You have to increment i and j after your bigger if statement